# Is there a way in SQL to use max date logic but ignore the max date if it's associated with a 0 value?

Tags: sql, date

This is my query:

```sql
select distinct Material_Number as 'Material #', Quantity, MAX(date) as 'Max Date' 
FROM table
group by Material_Number, Quantity
```

Which returns something like so:

```
Material #   Quantity    Max Date
-----------------------------------    
E706972      0.00        2020-11-03    
E706972      11025.00    2020-10-30    
E706973      10525.00    2020-11-03    
E706974      1025.00     2020-11-03    
E706974      0.00        2020-10-30
```

Right now, my query is only returning the max date value and the quantities associated with it by material #. What I need is to use future information to filter past information. I need to change my query so that for any given material #, if the latest date has a 0 value for quantity, it will filter out the material # entirely. However, if there is a 0 value associated with a material #, but not for the latest date, then just filter out the 0 value and leave the non-zero quantity in the results. So my new query would ideally return this:

```sql
Material #   Quantity    Max Date
-----------------------------------       
E706973      10525.00    2020-11-03    
E706974      1025.00     2020-11-03
```

Because the 2 rows associated with material #E706972 had a 0 value on the latest date (11-03), both rows were filtered out. As for E706974, since it does have a 0 value, but since it's not the latest date (11-03 > 10-30), the non-zero row remains while the 0 row is filtered out.

This is my 1st stack overflow question, so please feel free to ask for more detail/ask me questions. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? Also, SSMS is specifically for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: I am using SQL Server, MySQL tag was a mistake, I will remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
SELECT Material_Number as 'Material #',
       MAX(Quantity), MAX(date) as 'Max Date' 
FROM table
GROUP BY Material_Number
HAVING MAX(DATE) <> MAX(CASE WHEN Quantity = 0 THEN Date END) OR
       MAX(CASE WHEN Quantity = 0 THEN Date END) IS NULL;
```

Assuming you have no more than two rows (as in in your sample data), then returns a quantity that is not `0`, but only for materials where the final quantity is not `0`.

Comment: I am doing some testing real quick, may need to add some follow up commentary